# Adding numbers in python and in line using function recursion

Tags: python, recursion, arraylist, sequence, addition

Hey guys I have a code like this

```
def add_sum(n):
    numStr = str(n)
    sum = 0

    for i in range(len(num_str)):
        sum += int(numStr[])
    return sum
print(add_sum(546))
```

I want the answer to be this way.

output: 5 + 4 + 6 = 15

How can I make this work for me?

Comment: This code full of errors (and doesn't have recursion). Is this a test question?

Comment: Yeah, I am an upcoming programmer, and I want to learn, that's why I want a code related to that output.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this non-recursive code.

```
def add_sum(n):
    temp = list(str(n))
    ans = 0
    for i in temp:
        ans += int(i)

    print(f"{' + '.join(temp)} = {ans}")    


for i in range(3):
    num = int(input())
    add_sum(num)
```

```
Output:

546
5 + 4 + 6 = 15
258
2 + 5 + 8 = 15
6985
6 + 9 + 8 + 5 = 28
```

Comment: Use a for-loop and call ```add_sum()```.

Comment: Updated answer. Please check.

Comment: Hello @Ram
Please advance it for me this way.
an example:


7988 => 7 + 9 + 8 + 8 = 32 ==> 3 + 2 =5

You keep adding the values until it becomes single digit number is reacherd.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_sum = lambda number: sum([int(x) for x in str(number)])
```

If you wanna do it the string conversion way

Edit: I assume you were referring to the loop, when you mentioned "recursion"?

If you want to loop over digits of a number, you can also use module 10 and divide the number each time.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with recursion that does not convert int to str (which is kind of an expensive operation):

```
def add_sum(n):
    return 0 if n == 0 else n % 10 + add_sum(n // 10)
```

If you prefer a solution without recursion:

```
def add_sum(n):
    result = 0
    while n != 0:
        result += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return result
```

If you want to convert int to str:

```
def add_sum(n):
    return sum(map(int, str(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
def add_sum(n):
    numStr = str(n)
    sum1 = 0
    for i in range(len(numStr)):
        sum1 += int(numStr[i])
    return ' + '.join([str(x) for x in n]),sum1
i,j=add_sum('546')
print(i,'=',j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_sum(n):
    numStr = str(n)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(numStr)):
        sum += int(numStr[i])
    return sum
print(add_sum(546))
```

This is the correct version of your code!

You can use your function With recursion like this!

```
def add_sum(n, sum=0):
    if n == 0:
        return sum
    else:
        sum += n % 10
    return add_sum(int(n/10), sum)
print(add_sum(546))
```

here you go! sol. with recursion

```
def add_sum(n, sum=0, orignal=0):
    if n == 0:
        return(f"{orignal} => {' + '.join(str(orignal))} = {sum}")
    elif orignal == 0:
        orignal = n
        sum += n % 10
    else:
        sum += n % 10
    return add_sum(int(n/10), sum, orignal)
print(add_sum(54236))

Output:
    54236 => 5 + 4 + 2 + 3 + 6 = 20
```

Comment: Yes, Now
How can I have the output as follows:
example:
564 => 5 + 6 + 4 = 14
746 = >7 + 4 + 6 = 17

In that order.

Comment: you mean you need to print it like 564 => 5 + 6 + 4 = 14?

Comment: Yes, sir.
That's how I want it to be be

Comment: Updated, Please check!

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
def add(num):
    num_ = str(num)
    if (len(num_) == 1):
        return int(num)
    else:
        x = add(num_[1:])
    return (x + int(num_[0]))
```